# Installed updated Openssl on Centos 7 before compiling new updated nginx, but where to put source directory?

Tags: nginx, installation, openssl, centos7

I am trying to update nginx on a Centos 7 server. I needed an updated openssl, so I installed openssl-1.1.1, but into `/tmp/openssl-1.1.1`, not realizing it would be needed later for the nginx update. I did the nginx `make` command, using that openssl directory, and it worked. However, I have not done `make install` yet.

Should I reinstall openssl into a more appropriate source directory, or can I just leave it as it is, and go ahead and compile nginx? Or, is it possible to just move the openssl-1.1.1 directory, and reinstall it from there, then compile nginx? What is the best place to install openssl?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Installing OpenSSL into `/tmp/openssl-1.1.1` is not a good idea if you plan to dynamically link Nginx against OpenSSL, some `systemd-tmpfiles` default configuration will clean up `/tmp` sooner or later to remove old files.

Did you consider to use the meanwhile available `openssl11-libs` and `openssl11-devel` RPM packages from EPEL 7 rather building OpenSSL by yourself (to also cover future security updates)? It's providing the same OpenSSL version like RHEL/CentOS 8 does.

Before building, you need to extend `$CFLAGS` and `$LDFLAGS` slightly, e.g. like this:

```
export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS $(pkg-config --cflags openssl11)"
export LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS $(pkg-config --libs openssl11)"
```

Or, if `./configure` supports passing a pkg-config `*.pc` file directly, use `openssl11` there.